# How to configure the intranet .htaccess file

Tags: file, .htaccess, configuration-files, intranet

I want to allow only my LAN IP addresses to access the web site directory and files are kept on web server which has public ip & my lan pc's are connecting using ISP public ip address so my question is how can allow only my LAN ip & which ip i need to add in the htacces file.
Below is the my .htaccess sample so please add require changes into it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
# slashes.
# If your page resides at
# then use
# RewriteBase /mypage/test1/

RewriteBase /SITE_FOLDER
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Also bro there are some other .htacess files in side the web site folder should i remove then or kept them because they are blank ???

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use code like this in your .htaccess file.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.0.1/24
```

Of course use your LAN IP address and subnet instead. For example using a `192.168.0.1/24` will allow PC's with a range of IP's from `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254`. The IP you will need to use is the internal IP not your public. Typically something like `192.168.0.1` or `10.0.0.1` etc.